# Extending Rails models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Rails models come with certain built-in methods like this:

```
Appointment.new
Appointment.find(1)
```

How do I add more methods to `Appointment`? It's apparently not done by adding methods to `app/models/appointment.rb`. Doing that adds methods to an *instance* of `Appointment`, but I want to add methods to `Appointment` itself. How do I do that?

Comment: btw, the term you're looking for is "class methods" (as opposed to "instance methods").

Comment: Okay, thanks. I was wondering what that was.

Comment: `MyClass.new` is how you initiate a standard Ruby class instance btw, it has nothing to do with Rails.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
def self.some_method
  #do stuff
end
```

Comment: In case you want to investigate further: They are called "class methods" or "static methods", depending on the language you came from (or both, if you come from python).

Answer (score 3):

Mark's answer is definitely right, but you will also see the following syntax when defining class methods:

```
class Appointment
  class << self
    def method1
      # stuff
    end

    def method2
      # stuff
    end

    def method3
      # stuff
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Is there any benefit from doing it this way though? Cause it seems like a horribly confusing way otherwise; `class << self` makes no sense at all!

Comment: @Ashley I can think of at least two benefits of this syntax. 1) You don't have to write `self` before every method if you have a bunch of class methods and 2) All your class methods are indented and grouped together. Anything is confusing if you've never seen it before, but it's definitely used by a lot of Ruby devs. Here it is in the Rails active record source: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb#L426

Comment: I've indeed seen this practice a lot (and shamelessly used it once or twice before myself), but it still seems strange, almost a language hack like `[*$<]`, which while perfectly valid, is unnecessarily cryptic, especially in open-source code where you want outsiders to understand and embrace it. Ruby's an elegant language the majority of the time, it seems such a shame to spoil it with overly-smart code such as this where it can be helped.

Comment: A must read about class << self :  http://yehudakatz.com/2009/11/15/metaprogramming-in-ruby-its-all-about-the-self/